# convert string to object from html input element

Tags: javascript, html, string, object

I have a `textarea` element which takes object types as an input
like

```
{
  name: "root",
  backlog: [
    {name: "log#1"},
  ]
}
```

Accessing the data returns it as a string

Is there a simple way to convert the `String` to that specific `javascript object` without using regex filters? Just removing the outer quotation marks?

Comment: You can do it with `eval()`, but this will also evaluate function calls so it's dangerous.

Comment: Is this not something [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) can do? or there's more to it?

Comment: If you can validate the string as a valid JSON syntax a simple JSON.parse will do the work, if not you will have to format the string before using JSON.parse

Comment: i would say to not force the user to enter input like "a = 0;", that would be inconvenient. do not do this unless you really need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [json5](https://github.com/json5/json5) or [Relaxed JSON](https://github.com/phadej/relaxed-json) library.

here is example using `json5` library

```js
let string = `  {
    name: "root",
    backlog: [
      {name: "log#1"},
      ]
    }`;
    
 let object = JSON5.parse(string);
 console.log(object)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/json5@^2.0.0/dist/index.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

To convert a string to a JSON, use: `JSON.parse(`*`[the input]`*`)`.

And, to convert it back to a string: `JSON.stringify(`*`[the input]`*`)`.

Comment: @seeman , note that you need to replace the single quotes with "&apos;" in the input string as json does something like `' + [input] + '`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly :

```js
const string = '{ name: "root", backlog: [{name: "log#1"}]}'
const jsonStr = string.replace(/(\w+:)|(\w+ :)/g, function(matchedStr) {
  return '"' + matchedStr.substring(0, matchedStr.length - 1) + '":';
});

const result = JSON.parse(jsonStr)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I considered this regex before but it keys containing dashes like `"key-val": "secret"` do "break" it

Comment: You can use this implementation replacing the regex by `/\w+.\w+:/g` and it would support those expressions you've mentioned

Comment: This will fail to parse e.g. `{"title": "Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan"}`.

Comment: You're right @user3840170. The regex I've proposed will not work as expected in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a simple, native approach you could simply stringify and then parse it using the intrinsic JSON object, i.e. something like this:

```
let yourObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(textareaVariable));
```

This works because stringify will essentially format the string into a JSON string with the appropriate syntax for a JSON document, which you can then parse into a standard object.

Answer (score 0):

Convert a JavaScript object into a string with `JSON.stringify()`.

Create a JSON string from a JavaScript object.

```
const obj = {name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York"};
const myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj); 
console.log(myJSON);
//Output: {"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}
```

Parse the data with `JSON.parse()`, and the data becomes a JavaScript object.

Creating an Object from a JSON String

```
const txt = {"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}
const obj = JSON.parse(txt);
console.log(obj.name + ", " + obj.age);
//Output:John, 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a JSON.parse call with some parameters to maintain the indetation.

```js
const text = '{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "address":{"city": "Tanger", "country": "Morocco"}}';

const obj = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(text), null, 2)
console.log(obj);
```